# How to make labels' size relative to the map in QGIS1.8?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I want to make my labels' size changed automatically with the scale of the map,so in the menu of "Layer labeling settings",I set the Text size" in map Unit".However,the labels in the selected layer disappeared.I turned off the "Scale-based visibility" and tried to set the size from 0.05 to 2000,but the labels still refused to meet me :P What should  I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could it be you told QGIS to render labels 20 degrees big?

Comment: As a followup to @underdark, what are your map units?  Feet, meters, degrees?

Comment: I've set my map unit to Decimal dgrees,for the scale is still wrong in QGIS1.8 if I set the map unit to meter(still unfixed?).I finally set the size to "0.0001"(in map unit,the minimum value),and the labels appeared.But the labels are still too big.How to make the labels smaller?

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to specify the size label so I used the advice in a Comment on this Question:

> I finally set the size to "0.0001"(in map unit,the minimum value),and the labels appeared.But the labels are still too big.How to make the labels smaller?

You make labels smaller, entering the small figures due to 'Expression string builder' with scale.